# How to store integer data with repeating format?

Tags: c++, parsing, opengl

I want to use OpenGL to draw lines, circles (and potentially polygons eventually, though my parser is easily extensible to that end). My input file looks like so:

```
L 0,0,175,55
L 22, 8, 75, 100
C 150, 200, 0
L 99, -50, 217, 77
Z

etc.
```

where Z denotes the end of the file and C/L denote circle and line data respectively. Thanks to some earlier Stack Overflow help and a bit of effort, I have been able to parse integer data from my input .txt file like so (all necessary libraries included elsewhere in the .cpp file itself):

```
void parseFile()
{
ifstream lines;
lines.open("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/lines.txt"); //Adjust to proper absolute path of test file
string currentLine;

while(getline(lines, currentLine))
{

    if(currentLine.empty()) //Check that there is no garbage data in the parser
        continue;

    istringstream iss(currentLine); //Convert line of data into input stream

    char type; // L, C or Z

    if(!(iss >> type))
       continue;

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'L': //If L, store as line (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        {
            char comma;
            int x0, y0, x1, y1;

            if(!(iss >> x0 >> comma >> y0 >> comma >> x1 >> comma >> y1))
            {

              cerr << "ERROR: Failed to read L: " << currentLine << endl;
              continue;
            }

           //STORE
           cout << "(" << x0 << ", " << y0 << ", " << x1 << ", " << y1 << ")" << '\n';

            break;
        }
        case 'C': //If C, store as circle data (center x, center y, int radius)
        {
            char comma;

            int xc, yc, rad;

            if(!(iss >> xc >> comma >> yc >> comma >> rad))
            {

              cerr << "ERROR: Failed to read C: " << currentLine << endl;
              continue;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 'Z': //If Z, end the parsing
        {
            break;
        }
        default:
            cerr << "ERROR: BAD INPUT " << currentLine << endl;
    }
}
}
```

My difficulties are, though I know the format of every line of input, and that it will be correct, I don't know how many lines there will be, or whether the structure will be something like L C L C, L L L L, or what have you. Line coordinates will always be parsed in sets of four as above, while circles will always be parsed in sets of three.

Thus, I want to store the points, so later, I can use OpenGL functions to manipulate/draw with them. I am not sure how to do this. My thought of using an arbitrarily large array and reading it in sets of 4/3 seems to be a poor solution, especially since I don't know whether or not two circles or lines will occur in a row, or whether one will follow the other, leaving me with mismatched data. A vector may be more suitable, as it will have a dynamically adjustable size but again, I am not sure how to effectively pull numbers from the vector in order to ensure I always draw correct primitives.

Any assistance/pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is saving memory important? or is readable code more important?

Comment: Certainly I value readable code over memory usage. The data input is just integer values, and a large file would probably contain only a few hundred.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

The code is a bit messy, but you should be able to clean it up and I hope you get the idea of it. Not sure if it's a good implementation but it seems alright to use.

See results and for testing at: http://ideone.com/cr1GL9
Put everything in one class and made it deallocate on deconstructor: http://ideone.com/2Hyhqg

Below code outputs:

```
LINE: 11 12 13 14
LINE: 21 22 23 24
CIRCLE: 31 32 33
LINE: 41 42 43 44
CIRCLE: 51 52 53
POLYGON: [0]{11, 12} [1]{21, 22} [2]{31, 32} [3]{41, 42} [4]{51, 52}
```

Code:

```
//For testing
#include <iostream>

//Required to use vector
#include <vector>

//Base class for things to push on
class drawingObject { };

//Holds data for a circle
class drawingCircle : drawingObject {
    public:
        drawingCircle (int _xc, int _yc, int _rad) {
            xc = _xc;
            yc = _yc;
            rad = _rad;
        }

        int xc, yc, rad;
};

//Holds data for a line
class drawingLine : drawingObject {
    public:
        drawingLine (int _x0, int _y0, int _x1, int _y1) {
            x0 = _x0;
            y0 = _y0;
            x1 = _x1;
            y1 = _y1;
        }

        int x0, y0, x1, y1;
};

//Holds data for a polygon
class drawingPolygon : drawingObject {
    public:
        class Point {
            public:
                Point () {}
                Point (int _x, int _y) {
                    x = _x;
                    y = _y;
                }
                int x, y;
        };

        drawingPolygon (std::vector<drawingPolygon::Point>& points) {
            point = points;
        }

        std::vector<drawingPolygon::Point> point;
};

//Holds any type of item to draw
class drawingData {
    public:
        //So you can tell if it's a circle or line
        enum Type {
            LINE,
            CIRCLE,
            POLYGON
        };

        drawingData (Type _type, drawingObject* _data) {
            type = _type;
            data = _data;
        }

        Type type;
        drawingObject* data;
};

//Pushing on some object
void pushObject (std::vector<drawingData*>& vec, drawingData::Type type, drawingObject* obj) {
    vec.push_back(new drawingData(type, obj));
}

//Pushing on a line
void pushLine (std::vector<drawingData*>& vec, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    pushObject(vec, drawingData::Type::LINE,
        reinterpret_cast<drawingObject*> (new drawingLine(x0, y0, x1, y1))
    );
}

//Pushing on a circle
void pushCircle (std::vector<drawingData*>& vec, int xc, int yc, int rad) {
    pushObject(vec, drawingData::Type::CIRCLE,
        reinterpret_cast<drawingObject*> (new drawingCircle(xc, yc, rad))
    );
}

//Pusing on a polygon
void pushPolygon (std::vector<drawingData*>& vec, std::vector<drawingPolygon::Point>& points) {
    pushObject(vec, drawingData::Type::POLYGON,
        reinterpret_cast<drawingObject*> (new drawingPolygon(points))
    );
}

int main() {

    //Vector that holds drawingData pointers
    std::vector<drawingData*> myvector;

    //Pushing on some stuff
    pushLine   (myvector, 11, 12, 13, 14);
    pushLine   (myvector, 21, 22, 23, 24);
    pushCircle (myvector, 31, 32, 33);
    pushLine   (myvector, 41, 42, 43, 44);
    pushCircle (myvector, 51, 52, 53);

    std::vector<drawingPolygon::Point> points;
    points.push_back(drawingPolygon::Point(11, 12));
    points.push_back(drawingPolygon::Point(21, 22));
    points.push_back(drawingPolygon::Point(31, 32));
    points.push_back(drawingPolygon::Point(41, 42));
    points.push_back(drawingPolygon::Point(51, 52));
    pushPolygon(myvector, points);

    //Save some space
    myvector.resize(myvector.size());

    //Loop through each element
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < myvector.size();++i) {
        switch (myvector[i]->type) {
            case drawingData::Type::LINE: {
                //Make it easier to access the line data
                drawingLine* currLine = reinterpret_cast<drawingLine*>(myvector[i]->data);

                //Accessing elements
                std::cout << "LINE: " <<
                    currLine->x0 << " " << currLine->y0 << " " <<
                    currLine->x1 << " " << currLine->y1 << std::endl;

                break;
            }

            case drawingData::Type::CIRCLE: {
                //Make it easier to access the circle data
                drawingCircle* currCircle = reinterpret_cast<drawingCircle*>(myvector[i]->data);

                //Accessing elements
                std::cout << "CIRCLE: " <<
                    currCircle->xc << " " << currCircle->yc << " " << currCircle->rad << std::endl;

                break;
            }

            case drawingData::Type::POLYGON: {
                //Make it easier to access the polygon data
                drawingPolygon* currPolygon = reinterpret_cast<drawingPolygon*>(myvector[i]->data);

                //Accessing elements
                std::cout << "POLYGON: ";
                for (unsigned int i = 0;i < currPolygon->point.size();++i) {
                    std::cout << "[" << i << "]" << "{" << currPolygon->point[i].x << ", " << currPolygon->point[i].y << "} ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also don't forget to `delete` the classes that are `new`'ed! Otherwise you will get nasty memory leaks. You could write a deconstructor for `drawingData` to help with this. Ask me if you don't understand, in fact, if you don't understand/want explanation on anything, ask me. :)